# Temporary blocking all network access for a limited time while a CPU sensitive task is running

Tags: raspbian, python, networking

I'm trying to find a way to block all internet access (and local network access) to a Raspberry Pi 2 for a limited time while an important task is running.

The problem is, my Pi is doing a video recording and starts producing errors when other users connect while a recording is in progress. So my failsafe idea is to watch the schedule for recordings and take the Pi into local-only mode while it's busy with that.

I'd monitor the schedule in Python, so a Python solution is preferred, but any scriptable commands will do.

A perfect solution would allow blocking local network access and remote access independently... I'm using the current Raspbian distribution.

Any tips on how to achieve that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to just renice the recording process so it gets all the CPU it needs?

Comment: This is a rather "hacky" solution that seems to attempt to avoid another problem that could potentially cause other issues that have not yet been identified. As much as I hate to be that over-opinionated StackExchange jerk who insists that your question should not be answered because you're asking the wrong question, this does not seem like the best solution. It's like the joke about the patient who tells a doctor, "It hurts when I do this", and the doctor admonishes the patient not to "do that". The solution to having problems with incoming network connections during recording shouldn't just

Comment: You really don't want to do this. What if you try to run this over SSH?

Comment: Why not just block users from accessing the device for that time period. Dont take down ethernet.. what if it doesnt come back up

Comment: @ppumkin - if the device doesn't come back, unplug, plug back in... just like any headless raspberry that becomes unresponsive. .Reg other comments: The recording is done by a software (tvheadend) that behaves badly when too much load happens - changing the software behavior is out of my reach. The goal here of an undisturbed recording has priority over everything else, including SSH access, so dropping network while a recording runs to prevent accidental access to the pi by anyone is a solution...

Comment: If it's in a remote place... who is gonna unplug and plug it back in? Just saying :)

Comment: @ppumkin - it's a headless server but well within reach of the person that wants his recordings bit error free...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a couple of options:

1. Take the interface down:

   ```
   /sbin/ifconfig eth0 down
   /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 down
   ```

   and to bring it back up:

   ```
   /sbin/ifconfig eth0 up
   /sbin/ifconfig wlan0 up
   ```
2. You could add a rule to your firewall using either UFW or iptables directly. UFW will block most incoming traffic by default.

   You will need to install UFW first:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ufw
   ```

   then enable it:

   ```
   sudo ufw enable
   ```

   then to block a specific port:

   ```
   sudo ufw deny 53
   ```

   you can remove thepreceeding rule with this command:

   ```
   ufw delete deny 53
   ```

   you may also need to restart UFW after changing the rules:

   ```
   sudo service ufw restart
   ```

More information on using UFW can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFW)

3. If using Ethernet you could pull the cable, or if using an external WiFi dongle remove it.

The first is probably easier, but the second will allow you to allow/disallow traffic by IP address, port, protocol etc.

You don't mention what model Pi you are using, but a better long term solution may be to get a second Pi that you can dedicate to just the video, or a model 3B, which may provide better performance because of its upgraded processor - compared to other models.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It's a pi2 running tvheadend, connected to a satellite usb card. It runs great with the one exception that you are not allowed to connect to it while a recording is running: On connect it serves a channel list and all EPG data to the connecting client and at that exact point the running recording is damaged. When a recording is not running, access is needed to set timers for future recordings and to download recordings. Just blocking the 2 ports tvheadend uses might be a good idea. Can you add the exact commands how to block a specific port and unblock it later?

Answer (score 4):

Expanding on @MSalters comment, you should really try to play with [priority](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/nice.1.html) and see if that solves the problem. You have two options here:

- either you start your recording process with increased priority using `nice -n-10 recording_command`,
- or you decrease the priority of the server process your users connect to. Assuming a web server, that would be `renice +10 -u www-data`.

Both commands should be run as root.

Comment: Giving a very CPU heavy task, such as video encoding, a niceness of less than zero might very well bring just about everything else on the system to a halt.  So, if you do try using nice on your recording command, be prepared for the whole system to go unresponsive to every method of communication for the duration of the encoding.

Comment: @PatrickM, I don't think it's that drastic if you're not using real-time priorities. Also, if it's about encoding a live recording, it's not likely to use _all_ available CPU.

Comment: This might be a solution, if the recording process could be separated from the other disturbing processes. In my scenario that is not the case, therefore the question here is how to block all network access or at least some ports for a limited time...

Comment: @576i I don't quite understand what you mean by *separated*, starting a process with `nice` doesn't require you to manage it afterwards in any way, it simply gets higher priority which the scheduler takes into account. However, if you insist on disabling the network interface, I'm not going to convince you here.

Answer (score 1):

You can give realtime priority to the video recording task using the `chrt` command, which will schedule this task whenever there is anything for it to do. The other tasks will only get CPU time while the recording task is waiting for the disk, or idle.

Comment: Which `chrt` parameters do you recommend?

Comment: If you just have one realtime process, the actual parameters don't matter -- realtime processes are scheduled before non-realtime. The strategy and priority settings are for resolving situations where two realtime processes are runnable.

Answer (score -1):

Have you ensured that your power supply is up to snuff?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=42572

I had issues with intermittent connectivity that turned out to be power related.

Comment: Actually, this comment is not as stupid, as other people may think. The recording is done via USB using a USB satellite card onto a USB stick, so power could be an issue... Still blocking all network would save me from having to research that...